# MVC Request URL Too Long with file return issue

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to send 500 GUIDs to MVC controller, get some data based of this Id's and return excel sheet. I have a POST method on my controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult ExportToExcel(List<string> contractIds)
    {
        var contracts = SearchContracts.ExportToExcel(string.Join(",", contractIds));

        byte[] filecontent = ExcelExportHelper.ExportExcel(contracts, "Report", false, null);
        return File(filecontent, ExcelExportHelper.ExcelContentTypeXlsx, "Report.xlsx");
    }
```

If I do it way of AJAX, I need to have AJAX `type: "POST"`, everything looks OK, but no file is returned to client:

```
function exportToExcel() {
    var selectedContractsId = getSelectedContracts();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "Search")",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(selectedContractsId),
        dataType: "json"
    });
}
```

and if I do it as standard MVC action and change controller method to `HttpVerbs.Get`, file is returned to client but I have a problem with URL Too Long exception and update Web.config `maxUrlLength` parameter is not working for me, because 500 GUIDs is not maximum, you can choose e.g. 10000 GUIDs and it is 370 000 characters in query string.

```
function exportToExcel() {
    var selectedContractsId = getSelectedContracts();

    location.href = '@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "Search")?contractIds=' + selectedContractsId;
}
```

Comment: You cannot return a file using ajax. But you can do an ajax call to a method that generates the file and then in the success callback, use `location.href` to navigate to a method which downloads it.

Comment: Good idea, but I am not sure if i can imagine how to generate file in one method and how to download it in another method.. can you give me some advice please?

Comment: Just found a dupe that shows how you could do it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thx, problem solved!